# How to get the "host" object java

Tags: java

I need to get the "host" object of another object. Here an example

Suppose I have the

```
class Peer {
    final Service service;
    public Peer(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }
    public void ping() {
        service.ping();
    }
}
```

and

```
class Service {
    public String hola() {
        this.getPeer()? //HERE I NEED SOME COMMAND TO GET the Peer object, is this possible?
    }
}
```

Then in Service class, I need to get the peer object. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the `Peer` object inside your `Service` object while creating an instance of `Service`, that's the only way for retrieving it.
Create inside `Service` a constructor which accepts `Peer`

```
class Service {
    Peer peer;
    public Service(Peer peer){
        this.peer = peer;
    }

    public Peer getPeer() {
        return peer;
    }

    public String hola() {
        Peer peer = getPeer();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thing is:

```
this.getPeer()? //HERE I NEED SOME COMMAND TO GET the Peer object, is this possible?
```

There is no "command" to do that. Simply spoken: java objects have no notion of the context they were created in. The only way for an instance of `Service` to know about the `Peer` that created it: for example by passing a reference to that `Service` object, for example within its constructor. Or by having a setter method on the Service class that allows you to do that.

But of course: that sounds like the wrong way. A service instance should be really independent of the Peers using it! In other words: if it really makes sense that a Service knows one (or multiple?!) peers, then the Service class needs a field to "remember" that relationship. But at least the example given here rather suggests that your Service should not at all know (or care) about the Peers using it!